# Return array of data instead of Dictionary - Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I need post data like array, but I send it always like this:

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Král Lávra",
            "author": "Karel Havlíček Borovský",
            "yearOfRelease": "1920",
            "price": "120",
            "SubjectId": 1,
            "UserId": 2,
            "SchoolId": 1
        },
      ]
}
```

I want show result like this:

```
[
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Král Lávra",
            "author": "Karel Havlíček Borovský",
            "yearOfRelease": "1920",
            "price": "120",
            "SubjectId": 1,
            "UserId": 2,
            "SchoolId": 1
        },
]
```

I use sequelize to connection between database MySQL. This is my code for findAll books:

```
let books = await ctx.db.Book.findAll({
        where: {
            UserId: id
        },
    })
```

Then I only post to

```
ctx.body=  {
   books
}
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: I don't know Sequelize, but I'd guess just `ctx.body = books;` without the surrounding braces?

Comment: What are you using for your server to send the response back? Koa?

Comment: Oh i got it thanks man!!! Sorry for my stupid question... :D